# Nuget package that has no dependents

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am using mspec ([machine specification](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications)) unit test framework for .NET project.

I used nuget to get all required packages.

There is a specific package, that is not part of the code. It is the "Console" application for the mspec that I used to run my unit tests from outside VS, from the command line.
([It is located here](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications.runner.console)): 
When I use Nuget to install it, Nuget doesn't add it to the normal "packages.config" file inside of the Test project.
It is adding it to a "packages.config" folder that exists in ".nuget" folder.

But when my colleague open the project and build, his VS doesn't get that package.

How to change that, to force VS to get the package automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nuget doesn't add it to the normal "packages.config" file inside of the Test project. It is adding it to a "packages.config" folder that exists in ".nuget" folder.

That is because you are using NuGet 2.7 or later and **have a solution that is still configured by old package restore method "MSBuild-integrated restore"**. This will cause builds to fail with an error stating that you have not given consent to restore packages. Visual Studio will skip automatic package restore.

> How to change that, to force VS to get the package automatically?

To resolve this question, you can follow below steps:

1. Close Visual Studio to avoid file potential file locks and conflicts.
2. If using TFS: a. Remove nuget.exe and nuget.targets from the solution's .nuget folder and remove those files from the solution workspace. a. Retain nuget.config with the disableSourceControlIntegration setting as explained in [Omitting packages with Team Foundation Version Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control#omitting-packages-with-team-foundation-version-control).
3. If not using TFS: a. Remove the .nuget folder from the solution and the solution workspace.
4. Edit each project file in the solution, remove the <RestorePackages> element, and remove any references to the nuget.targets file. For more detail information, you can refer to [Migrating to automatic restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore).